# Invalid quantifer error using Regular Expression (UK Telephone numbers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am getting the error "Invalid Quantifier" when using this regex:

```
^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$
```

Infact ive tried a few UK telephone number regex's from the regex librairy but im getting the same error all the time. If anyone can help id be much appreciative!

Answer (score 1):

You get the same error if you simply run this:

```
new RegExp("^(((+44\s?\d{4}|(?0\d{4})?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((+44\s?\d{3}|(?0\d{3})?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((+44\s?\d{2}|(?0\d{2})?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$");
```

... so you'd better forget about jQuery and Form Validator until you get the regexp right.

The JavaScript console says this:

> Error: invalid quantifier
>   +44s?d{4}|(?0d{4})?)s?d{3}s?d{3})|((+44s?d{3}|(?0d{3})?)s?d{3}s?d{4})|((+44s?d{2}|(?0d{2})?)s?d{4}s?d{4}))(s?#(d{4}|d{3}))?$

The `+` quantifier means `one or more` is used to modify a previous rule, e.g.:

```
A+ --> One or more A's
\d+ --> One or more digits
```

So you need something to quantify:

```
(((+ --> Nothing to modify
```

Comment: +1 for the excellent analysis. But you forgot to finish by explaining how to search for an actual plus sign in the input string. The final part is that the plus sign should be escaped - ie `(((\+ --> Search for a plus sign.`

Comment: @Spudley Rather than forgetting, I just couldn't figure out what the expression is supposed to match. UK phone numbers appear to be way more complicate than Spain ones.

Comment: the `+44` part is the international component, so to find a Spanish number would need `+34` in the same place. The query is over-complicated though - he's allowing for all the different variants in spacing that people use, which adds a lot of unnecessary complexity (should just do a `str_replace(' ','',$input)` first).

Answer (score 0):

Use this, its from http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=uk%20tele

```
(\s*\(?0\d{4}\)?(\s*|-)\d{3}(\s*|-)\d{3}\s*)|(\s*\(?0\d{3}\)?(\s*|-)\d{3}(\s*|-)\d{4}\s*)|(\s*(7|8)(\d{7}|\d{3}(\-|\s{1})\d{4})\s*)
```